# Smarty nested foreach with associative keys problem

Tags: task-parallel-library, smarty

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" id="pm-grid">
            {foreach from=$results key=k item=video_data}
            
                {foreach from=$data item=item key=key}
                {include file='item-video-obj.tpl'}
      
               {$item.name}
                </li>
            {/foreach}
            </li>
            {/foreach}
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div></div>
```

I want to use two foreach in the same column but it overflows the column. I don't understand how to do it, can you help me?

Comment: you want to add 2nd foreach loop data as <li> item?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.